# implication of using ufw for azure cloud Ubuntu VM, port opened is not working as expected

Tags: powershell, azure, ubuntu, firewall, ufw

I have a cloud `Ubuntu VM` which is in some `resource group` of company's subscription.

I do not have access to `azure portal`.

I had opened up the ports whichever relevant in `azure portal` while choosing `Virutal Machine`. Now I need some more ports to gets opened up, wherein I have hurdles and complications regards to that.

Command `ip address` gives following ip for `eth0` as it is default configuration.

`inet 10.0.0.4/24`

Wherein some dynamic ip assigned to this host `13.71.17.175` by `azure`, using which we access services whichever we run. I do not know how this routing happens. Now I need to open up few more ports, and I do not have access to `azure portal`.

I observed uncomplicated firewall,- `ufw` enablement works but leads to complication, as it overrides firewall configurations, I need to completely port all firewall configurations including `ssh` port,- `22` provisioning.

So `sudo ufw enable` is very dangerous on `azure` cloud Linux variant VMs. On the same pact we should do `sudo ufw disable`, else it is lockout situation if ssh port not provisioned by `ufw`. Once in fact I had requested my Senior Folk and ran the command `sudo ufw disable` through some `Azure Virtual Machine Serial Console` for the `UbuntuVM`

Now my question is basically,

`sudo ufw allow from any to any port 18081 proto tcp`

is not working.

After it is done, as per my observation, I am not able to access `http:\\13.71.17.175:18081\`

What `ufw` command I have to run in order to bridge `10.0.0.4` with dynamic ip assigned to host in `azure` portal,- `13.71.17.175`

Service runs on 0.0.0.0:18081 and it is `nexus` service

```
$ netstat -tuplen|grep 18081
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:18081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          114209     -
```

From my machine, somehow `test-netconnection 13.71.17.175 -p 18081` succeeded in `powershell`. But I do not know why `http:\\13.71.17.175:18081\` didn't turn up.

And one more important thing, even restart of `UbuntuVM` in `azure` portal didn't turn off `ufw`.

Once this port is up & running, I have to port all firewall configuration to uncomplicated firewall,- `ufw`, that's how I could succeed with my config. and I do not have any other choice.

Now I had configured all the ports and enable `ufw`, but it looks like it requires restart. And I didn't do any bridging or routing to any other ip, rather opened up the ports in the present system. In order to enable `ufw`,  system restart is required.

```
$ sudo ufw enable
Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation (y|n)? y
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup
```

I had opened all the required ports say,

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw allow http
sudo ufw allow https
sudo ufw allow from any to any port 3306
sudo ufw allow from any to any port 18081
sudo ufw allow from any to any port 15672
sudo ufw allow from any to any port 8081
sudo ufw allow from any to any port 5672
sudo ufw allow from any to any port 5671
```

Here if `ssh` is not provisioned, then I have to go back to `Azure` portal to disable `ufw` :(